# Dropping regularity assumption in an exercise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am dealing with the following exercise: let $f$ from $R$ to $R$ a locally integrable function such that:
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2(f(x)+f(y)).$$

Prove that there exists $a$ such that $f(x)=ax^2$.

Hint: assume first $f$ to be $C^\infty$.

Now, I easily proved it for $f$ in $C^\infty$, deriving first in $x$ and then in $y$. But I can't see how to drop this assumption.
Distributional derivatives could work? Anyway, I can't see how to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate in $x$ from $0$ to $1$. You get

$$\int_0^1f(t+y)dt+\int_0^1f(t-y)dt=2\int_0^1 f(t)dt+2f(y)$$
Hence
 $$\int_y^{1+y}f(u)du+\int_{-y}^{1-y}f(u)du=2\int_0^1 f(t)dt+2f(y)$$

Now as $f$ is locally integrable,$\displaystyle F_1(y)=\int_y^{1+y}f(u)du$ and $\displaystyle F_2(y)=\int_{-y}^{1-y}f(u)du$ are continuous, hence $f(y)$ is continous. As $f$ is continous, $F_1$ and $F_1$ are differentiable, and $f$ is differentiable, etc. Hence by induction, $f$ is ${\mathcal C}^{\infty}$.